# How to bind database in Syncfusion Bar Chart on Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, syncfusion

I tried to use the code on its documentation but it's still not running even if it's static data. Here is the code on the link that I've used but it is not connected to the database. Here are the pictures of the codes I've used:

```
//CS File(I JUST PUT HERE)

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts;

namespace EJ2MVCSampleBrowser.Controllers.Chart
{
    public partial class ChartController : Controller
    {
        // GET: RoundedColumn
        public ActionResult RoundedColumn()
        {
            List<RoundedColumnChartData> chartData = new List<RoundedColumnChartData>
            {
                  new RoundedColumnChartData { x= "BGD", y= 106, text= "Bangaladesh" },
                  new RoundedColumnChartData { x= "BTN", y= 103, text= "Bhutn" },
                  new RoundedColumnChartData { x= "NPL", y= 198, text= "Nepal" },
                  new RoundedColumnChartData { x= "THA", y= 189, text= "Thiland" },
                  new RoundedColumnChartData { x= "MYS", y= 250, text= "Malaysia" }
            };
            ViewBag.dataSource = chartData;
            ViewBag.font = new { fontWeight = "600", color = "#ffffff" };
            return View();
        }
        public class RoundedColumnChartData
        {
            public string x;
            public double y;
            public string text;
        }
    }
}
```

```
//CSHTML File (I JUST PUT HERE)

<script src="~/Scripts/theme-color.js"></script>
    <div class="control-section">
        <div style="text-align:center">

            @Html.EJS().Chart("container").Series(series =>
       {
           series.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).XName("x").YName("y")
           .CornerRadius(cr=>cr.BottomLeft(10).BottomRight(10).TopLeft(10).TopRight(10))
           .Marker(mr => mr.DataLabel(dl => dl.Visible(true).Position(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LabelPosition.Top).Font(ff => ff.FontWeight("600").Color("#ffffff"))))
           .DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Name("Tiger").Add();

       }).PrimaryXAxis(px => px.Interval(1).MajorGridLines(mg=>mg.Width(0))
       .LabelStyle(ls=>ls.Color("#ffffff")).TickPosition(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.AxisPosition.Inside)
       .LabelPosition(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.AxisPosition.Inside).ValueType(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ValueType.Category)
            ).PrimaryYAxis(py => py.Minimum(0).Maximum(300).Interval(50)
            .MajorGridLines(mg => mg.Width(0)).LabelStyle(ls=>ls.Color("transparent"))
            .MajorTickLines(mg => mg.Width(0)).LineStyle(mg => mg.Width(0))
            ).Title("Trade in Food Groups").ChartArea(area => area.Border(br=>br.Color("transparent"))
            ).Tooltip(tt => tt.Enable(false)).LegendSettings(lg => lg.Visible(false)
            ).Load("load").PointRender("pointRender").Loaded("loaded").Render()
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;">
            Source:
            <a href="https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/extinction-countdown/tiger-populations-increasing/" target="_blank">blogs.scientificamerican.com</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  
  <script>


        
        var pointRender = function (args) {
            var selectedTheme = location.hash.split('/')[1];
            selectedTheme = selectedTheme ? selectedTheme : 'Material';
            if (selectedTheme && selectedTheme.indexOf('fabric') > -1) {
                args.fill = fabricColors[args.point.index % 10];
            }
            else if (selectedTheme === 'material') {
                args.fill = materialColors[args.point.index % 10];
            }
            else {
                args.fill = bootstrapColors[args.point.index % 10];
            }
        };
        var count = 0;
        var loaded = function (args) {
            args.chart.loaded = null;
            setInterval(
                function () {
                    if (count === 0) {
                        args.chart.series[0].dataSource = [
                            { x: 'Tea', y: 206, text: 'Bangaladesh' },
                            { x: 'Misc', y: 123, text: 'Bhutn' },
                            { x: 'Fish', y: 48, text: 'Nepal' },
                            { x: 'Egg', y: 240, text: 'Thiland' },
                            { x: 'Fruits', y: 170, text: 'Malaysia' }
                        ];
                        args.chart.animate();
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if (count === 1) {
                        args.chart.series[0].dataSource = [
                            { x: 'Tea', y: 86, text: 'Bangaladesh' },
                            { x: 'Misc', y: 173, text: 'Bhutn' },
                            { x: 'Fish', y: 188, text: 'Nepal' },
                            { x: 'Egg', y: 109, text: 'Thiland' },
                            { x: 'Fruits', y: 100, text: 'Malaysia' }
                        ];
                        args.chart.animate();
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if (count === 2) {
                        args.chart.series[0].dataSource = [
                            { x: 'Tea', y: 156, text: 'Bangaladesh' },
                            { x: 'Misc', y: 33, text: 'Bhutn' },
                            { x: 'Fish', y: 260, text: 'Nepal' },
                            { x: 'Egg', y: 200, text: 'Thiland' },
                            { x: 'Fruits', y: 30, text: 'Malaysia' }
                        ];
                        args.chart.animate();
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }, 2000);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: The link you have shared is your local system link that is wrong.
http://localhost:54079/Chart/RoundedColumn#/material

Comment: Hello sir! I've shared the document link where I used the codes for static chart

Comment: Your words "Here's the documentation I used" contain your local path, not documentation's one.

Comment: Edit description: 

I am very new in Syncfusion and I badly need help how to integrate Syncfusion chart in ASP.Net MVC.

 I tried to use the code above but in still not working even it's static data. The code above is not connected to the database.

Comment: # 1: it's still not running even if it's static data We have prepared a sample with a snippet. The chart is rendering fine as expected. We have attached a tested sample for your reference. Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ColumnChart71318850.zip If you are still facing problem, please try to replicate an issue in above sample or share us issue reproduced sample so that it will be helpful for further analysis. # 2: How to bind database in Syncfusion Bar Chart We have prepared sample to bind the data to chart using SQL Server Database. Sample : https://w